# One method for two models. How to pass name of model as variable to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, relationship, activesupport-concern

I have two methods in two different controllers (Posts & Boards). They are almost same. The difference is only model-instance-association name. To DRY this I think to write the method in module, but how to share it between Post and Board?

```
def init_post_comments
    @user = current_user
    a = @user.posts.pluck(:id) # not very nice...
    b=params[:post_ids] ||= []
    b = b.map(&:to_i)
    follow = b - a
    unfollow = a - b
    follow.each do |id| # checkbox just checked
      @post = Post.find_by_id(id)
      if @post.users.empty?
        @post.update_attribute(:new_follow, true)
      end
      @user.posts << @post
    end
    unfollow.each do |id| # if checkbox was unchecked
      @post = Post.find_by_id(id)
      remove_post_from_user(@post)# here we destroy association
    end
    if follow.size > 0
      get_post_comments_data
    end

    redirect_to :back

  end
```

**UPDATE** Ok, if I'll move the methods to model's concern how I should work with associations here? Here `@user.posts.pluck(:id)` and here `@user.boards.pluck(:id)` with what I can replace posts and boards so it can work with both of them?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific? What is a Board? What are you trying to accomplish, specifically?

Comment: You would include the module in both of those classes, and then you can call it on instances of either class.

Comment: @brito if in my code you'll replace Post-@post-posts with Board-@board-boards it will be same method, but for another model. For now I write the code twice in two different controllers PostsController and BoardsController. But nevermind, it can be Foo and Bar.

Comment: @MaxWilliams ok, but how this method should look like for shared module? This is a question.

Comment: Most of this is business logic and should go in the model, which, if it's a shared method via a module, can just refer to `self` if you want the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did it! I don't know if it's right way, but I DRY this code.

Two controllers:

```
posts_controller.rb

def init_comments
    if Post.comments_manipulator(current_user, params[:post_ids] ||= []) > 0
      @posts = Post.new_post_to_follow  
      code = []
      @posts.each do |post|
        group = post.group
        code = code_constructor('API.call')
      end
      Post.comments_init(get_request(code), @posts)
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end

boards_controller.rb

def init_comments
    if Board.comments_manipulator(current_user, params[:board_ids] ||= []) > 0
      @boards = Board.new_board_to_follow
      code = []
      @boards.each do |board|# подготовка запроса
        group = board.group
        code = code_constructor('API.call')
      end
      Board.comments_init(get_request(code), @boards)
    end
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

As you can see they are absolutely same.
In models `board.rb` and `post.rb` - `include CommentsInitializer`

And in `models\concerns`

```
module CommentsInitializer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

module ClassMethods
  def comments_manipulator(user, ids)
    relationship = self.name.downcase + 's'
    a = user.send(relationship).pluck(:id)
    b = ids.map(&:to_i)
    follow = b - a
    unfollow = a - b
    follow.each do |id| # start to follow newly checked obj
      @obj = self.find_by_id(id)
      if @obj.users.empty?
        @obj.update_attribute(:new_follow, true)
      end
      user.send(relationship) << @obj
    end

    unfollow.each do |id| # remove from following
      @obj = self.find_by_id(id)
      remove_assoc_from_user(@obj, user)#destroy relation with current user
    end

    follow.size
  end

  def comments_init(comments, objs)
    i = 0
    objs.each do |obj| # updating comments data
      if comments[i]['count'] == 0
        obj.update(new_follow: false)
      else
        obj.update(new_follow: false, last_comment_id: comments[i]['items'][0]['id'])
      end
      i += 1
    end
  end

  def remove_assoc_from_user(obj, user)
    user = user.id
    if user
      obj.users.delete(user)
    end
  end
end
```

My code works. If you know how to make it better please answer!